# MySQL memory leak: libmysqlclient.18

Tags: c++, mysql

I've tried days and night googling and reading the MySQL documents but I just can't seem to find out what possibly is causing a memory leak.

It seems it happens randomly and this is the only function which leaks.

CODE:

```
unsigned long numRowQuery(std::string query)
{
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    unsigned long num_rows;

    // connecting to database
    if(!mysql_real_connect(connection,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0))
    {
        std::cout << "Connection error: " << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
    }

    if (mysql_query(connection, query.c_str()))
    {
        std::cout << "MySQL query error: " << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    num_rows = mysql_num_rows(result);

    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(connection);
    mysql_library_end();
    return num_rows;
}
```

[image: instruments cropped]

Comment: The image is too way small and non-expandable, so it's basically useless.

Comment: hmm i can upload a new one, but if you open it in a new window, you can see it full sized.

Answer (score 0):

> If you enable multiple-statement support, you should retrieve results from calls to mysql_query() or mysql_real_query() by using a loop that calls mysql_next_result() to determine whether there are more results.

Some queries in your software may generate more results, therefore, you need to fetch everyone of them after issue the queries. try put the mysql_free_result function call in a loop like the following code:

```
while (mysql_next_result(connection) == 0)
{
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    if (result)
        mysql_free_result(result);
}
```

here is the documentation: [mysql_store_result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-store-result.html)